# Creating a route that hides the controller name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to create a route that hides my controllers name in the URL - effectively creating a default controller.

I used to use the below match route, however it no longer works since upgrading ruby.

```
match 'url/action', to: 'pages#action'
```

I can't seem to work out how to convert this into a new get style route, is anybody able to shed any light on the situation?

Answer (score 2):

Rails 4 routing:

```
get 'url/action' => 'pages#action'
```

or, to match all HTTP verbs:

```
match 'url/action', to: 'pages#action', via: :all
```

[Read more](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).